# Is there a good OCR-readable font

Tags: gnupg, ocr

As part of my backups, I would like to be able to print and later re-scan a Base64-encoded copy of my private key. Unfortunately, neither gocr nor tesseract seems to be able to properly read any font that I throw at them. I have tried Times New Roman, Courier New, and OCR-A. Are there any other fonts I should try?

Comment: May I ask why you wan to do this? Why not keep your key on a floppy or USB drive instead? Is it really worth printing on paper? Also, since you will presumably not be doing this very often, you could always copy it manually. That will be annoying but it will only take a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

This only partly answers you question: I will not provide a solution for OCRing your backup, but for an paper alternative I recommend using QR codes. I "stored" my revocation certificates as QR codes on paper myself and created them by applying `qrencode` on the ASCII-armored version of the key (thus the one you'd print anyway).

There's also [Paperkey](http://www.jabberwocky.com/software/paperkey/) and some other small scripts for doing so, but just piping it through `qrencode` worked very well for me. Make sure to try reading the code after printing, so you definitely know everything's fine!

I also printed the command to create the code below, and added the ASCII-armored version in plain text on the backside of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Using Arial with font size 16 or bigger;
2. When you scan, make sure you scan at DPI 200 or 300

and most OCR engines should be able to read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the OCR engine considered.

For gocr, FreeMono is the best, see gocr documentation.

For tesseract, DejaVu-Serif works well, see https://superuser.com/a/1543382/280936

For abbyocr, verdana is good, see [this comparison](https://www.splitbrain.org/blog/2010-06/15-linux_ocr_software_comparison)

See also this wrap-up: https://www.monperrus.net/martin/perfect-ocr-digital-data